# Why is still Android Studio using Hello World TextView?

Tags: android, android-studio

Everytime I create a new project in Android Studio, by default I get in my `MainActivity`, a `TextView` containing "Hello World", which every single time I need to remove it. Why that? Is there any option that can allow me to create a new project witout it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Everytime I create a new project in Android Studio, by default I get in my MainActivity, a TextView containing "Hello World",

That is because of the specific choices that you made in the new-project wizard. You chose to create an activity, and you chose an activity template that has that particular content.

> Is there any option that can allow me to create a new project witout it?

Opt not to create an activity when you create the new project. In other words, in this screen, choose "Add No Activity":

[image: Create New Project, Add Activity Screen]

Comment: Never thought you'll actually answer a question of mine. You're everywhere, Jeez! `Add No Activity` made the trick. Thank you so much for solving this annoying issue.